# Is there a way to update continiously server side data when there is no connection with client?

Tags: django, websocket, real-time, game-engine, django-channels

I am creating a Real-time browser multiplayer game in which you move squads around the globe and you can fight other squads nearby.
I am using django framework and I will use django-channels which uses webSockets for the real time notifications.

In the database each squad has it postion in latitude and longitude health, moral.

The problem is that, when you move a squad, and the user closes the browser, How can I keep updating that squad position to begin the interaction with possible nearby squads.

For example I want to move my squad from A to C, it will take 6 hours so I disconnect (close browser) after 30 min. BUT after 4 hours, my squad encounters a enemy squad in B and a fight should begin updating my as well enemy squad attributes (health, moral, squad stopped).
**How can I keep updating my squad postion while there is no user who pushes data (POST, GET, WebSocket) and trigger a change in the database.**

I came with Long-polling: Making request every x time (no need to be very frequent since movement is slow). But for this, Will I need to use a separate "polling server" or process?

Comment: How can the user be in the game when he has closed the game? Since it's a browser game, closing the browser should be analogous to exiting the game. If he is offline and not performing any actions at all, what are you supposed to update?

Comment: @Ken4scholars It is like an MMO (Travian, Ogame, Supremacy 1914) A game could last days or months: A user could do the action of making a squad move across USA for example, it will take several days, so I want to keep updating this squad position while the user is not connected.

Maybe what I want to do is beyond the Client-Server Architecture...

Comment: So, how would you know the updates to make to the position if there is no input from the user? on the hand, if the updates don't require user input then I see no problem either as you don't need to update the client which is not online

Comment: @Ken4scholars The user input would be just the latitude and longitude, then the squad would move in straight line to the new position.
Yes, the user would not need update when is not online but the **server should know** when 2 or more squads will encounter each other.
For example I connect and I see my squad encountered an enemy 2 hours ago (while I was disconnected) and there was a battle.